# jQuery stopwatch with milliseconds and spacebar as trigger

Tags: jquery, timer, space, stopwatch, milliseconds

I've just started with 'learning' jQuery, so I almost know nothing. But, I want a stopwatch, showing minutes, seconds and milliseconds. I'd like to start the timer by pressing spacebar, and also stop the timer by again pressing spacebar. Does anyone has an idea on how to do this? Remember, I'm pretty new to jQuery, so a good description would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but you might start reading at http://api.jquery.com/keydown/ or http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is to retrieve the current time using `new Date().getTime()`
and inside an interval compare the initial time we stored with the current time:

`currentTime - startTime = difference in MS`

now having that difference in MS we can easily do some basic math:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/enaxaq/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
var int, ms=0, s=0, m=0;

function swatch(){

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  int = setInterval(function(){
      var time = new Date().getTime(); 
      var dif = time-startTime;
      ms= dif%1000;
      s = Math.floor(dif/1000)%60;
      m = Math.floor(dif/1000/60)%60;
      $('#swatch').text( m+':'+s+':'+ms); 
  },1);

}


$(document).on('keydown', function( e ){
   if(e.keyCode == 32 && !int){
        swatch();
   }else{
     clearInterval(int);
     int=0;
   }
});
```

<kbd>**[OR THIS WAY (Read Rick's comments below)](http://jsbin.com/enaxaq/5/edit)**</kbd> for leading "0"s

```
  s = ('0'+ Math.floor(dif/1000)%60 ).slice(-2);
  m = ('0'+ Math.floor(dif/1000/60)%60 ).slice(-2);
```

Comment: +1 but: $('#swatch').text(('0'+m).slice(-2)+':'+('0'+s).slice(-2)+':'+ms); Just because it's prettier ;)

Comment: @RickCalder implemented your nice use of `.slice()` into the demo.

Comment: Nice, I was fiddling with this before I saw your answer, then realized how little I actually know about js >.< mine was so inelegant compared to yours I didn't bother posting it.

Comment: @RickCalder oh... :) curious to see your thoughts (I imagine you had issues with nulling the interval...or?). Any way, I hope you see how it's actually very easy to build it!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/b2bvu/ << my attempt...

Comment: @RickCalder ohh I see, nice attempt! Just I would not rely on a setInterval to do `++` with my values cause setInterval might change from time to time and from browser to browser (~12ms tick?), rather get the real time and always compare - to minimize errors

Comment: Yeah I noticed watching it run that once in a while it would run very fast, that's when I popped back here and saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery stopwatch example can be found here: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-date-and-time-2/online-jquery-stopwatch/

And for your start/stop using spacebar, use:

```
$('body').keyup(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 32){
       // user has pressed space
       ss();
   }
});
```